# Matplotlib why is my plot not correctly graphing data? Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize two different sets of data: actual, and ideal. Actual and ideal have the same time increments which is 0 to 30 in increments of 1. Actual and ideal both start at 1000 and both decrease to around 200ish. Both their y values differ a little each increment.

```
t = incs
a = data.pop('actual')
b = data.pop('ideal')
plt.plot(t,a)
plt.plot(t,b)
plt.show()
```

This is what I end up getting as a result.
[image]

How do I get it so it's two decreasing lines with larger intervals on x and y so it's not so squished?

Comment: Also, the lines should be pretty similar, I don't understand the huge difference.

Comment: Your results are represented in `data[...]`  as strings — you want to convert them to floats before plotting, e.g., `t = [float(t) for t in incs]`

Comment: @gboffi I don't know if this even allows mentions but I have been stuck on that for so long. Thank you a lot